# How to setup google cloud SQL locally

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, python-3.x

How do I set up google cloud SQL programmatically in python in a way that works both on GAE and the local test environment?

When I setup locally the console always says:

> MySQLdb is not installed or loaded.

But when I open the terminal and write python and python command line
environment runs. It works fine in the terminal but in GAE it says the
following in GAE console.

> The RDBMS API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.

I am using python 2.7.3 for GAE.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer official help/walk-through at below link.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/#Python_Using_a_local_MySQL_instance_during_development

The important things you need to follow are

1. Make sure MySql is installed locally and you can access it via typing MySQL in your terminal.
2. You'll have to install [MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) library in your python path. Follow its INSTALL guide and don't forget to change the mysql_config variable in site.cfg available in the downloaded folder, otherwise it won't install.
   Run the below command after setting up your site.cfg. Make sure you current directory in terminal is the MySQLdb which you just downloaded from [MySQLdb link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/)

   **sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python setup.py install**
3. Make a test database in your local MySql or import the live dump in that local database, so that your table structure is same for both local and live environment
4. Below is the simple code from above page which works on local as well as live environment

---

```
import os
import MySQLdb
import webapp2

INSTANCE_NAME = 'your-project-id:your-instance-name'

class SQ(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # Display existing guestbook entries and a form to add new entries.
        if (os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and
            os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')):
            db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/' + INSTANCE_NAME, db='guestbook', user='root')
        else:
            db = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, db='guestbook', user='root')

        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('select id,guestName,content from enteries')

        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            self.response.write("(id) " + str(row[0]) + " | (name) " + str(row[1]) + " | (content) " + str(row[2]) + "</BR>" )

        db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question again, it seems like you are saying that you have installed MySQLdb but it is not being discovered by GAE. Assuming the path isn't the issue, are you using the latest version of the SDK? One additional thing to check would be your runtime - are you using `python27` as your GAE Python version? Python 3.x is not compatible with AppEngine, so you will either be using `python` or `python27` in the `runtime` field in `app.yaml`. Not sure if you are saying that you can import it fine in the shell, but if not, you'll want to make sure it is on your path (Linux: `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/MySQLdb/"`).

In order to use Cloud SQL locally, you have to have the MySQLdb library installed. MySQLdb is a library that allows Python to connect with a MySQL database, and when you simulate Cloud SQL locally, what you are doing is setting up a connection to a local MySQL database. Therefore you need to install a library that can handle the Python->MySQL interaction, and MySQLdb is the one required by GAE.

If you're on Linux, run `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`. If you're on something else (or even Linux), you can find the library [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/).

Comment: I am suing Mac os x. And google app engine is now supported python 2.x

Comment: @user1799469 Do you have `python27` or `python` as your runtime variable in `app.yaml`? My best guess is that this has to do with either the version of the SDK or the runtime you are using.

Comment: I have python27 as a runtime environment.

Comment: @user1799469 And you are able to use MySQLdb outside of GAE?